# Calculating Total Possible Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I remember from my poker days the simple formula, `52*51`, to calculate all of the unique combinations in a deck of 52 cards.

What I would like to do is calculate the total number of possible combinations for any alphanumeric three-character sequence. Some valid sequences are: `aaa`, `111`, `m7g`, `g7m`, et cetera.

For example, if instead the input was simply `a`, `b`, and `c`, the output that I would be looking for is the following:

`aaa`, `aab`, `abb`, `aac`, `acc`, `aba`, `aca`, `baa`, `caa`, `bbb`, `bba`, `bbc`, `bab`, `bcb`, `abb`, `cbb`, `ccc`, `cca`, `ccb`, `cac`, `cbc`, `acc`, `bcc`.

However, in my case, the input will be `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` instead of `abc`.

I'm not quite sure the same approach works for the following scenario. Is `36*35*34` sufficient when `m7g` and `g7m`, for instance, are considered unique and valid?

**Disclaimer: I'm not sure I'm using the correct tags, so feel free to correct them!**

Comment: Why not abb?  Or abc?  Or any of the four others you left out?

Comment: @AsuraPath whoops youre right i forgot those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $36$ possible characters that can be in each of three positions, and hence the total number is $36^3$.

Comment: ok so the total would be `46,656`? easy enough. thanks so much.